# Woocommerce disable shopping cart based on user roles

Tags: plugins

Is there anyway to disable the shopping cart for guest users but have a quote only option and have the shopping cart function for wholesale users? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You'll probably have to create a custom function and then replace the woocommerce_add_to_cart action with your function. If user is not logged in show the quote form, if they are logged in and have a specific role show the add to cart button

Comment: Thanks for the comment Anagio. I couldn't think of any out of the box solutions too.

Answer (score 1):

The [Catalog Visibility Options](http://www.woothemes.com/products/catalog-visibility-options/) plugin sounds like it would do what you want.  It can disable the shopping features for "guests" and allow them for registered/logged in users.

Then if you want to add a Quote form you could use Gravity Forms + WooCommerce [Gravity Forms Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/gravity-forms-add-ons/).  You might be able to use the "conditional logic" options in GF to get it to only display the quote option for non-logged in users (not 100% sure on that part though).

The Product Add-on's extension also gives you the ability to add a checkbox/textbox/radio buttons to a product, however I don't think the view options can be set on that for guest/registered users.